# android divider not adapting to screen rotation

Tags: android, view

I have created a View which works fine in potrait mode, but when I try to set it to Landscape mode the View doesnt adapt or expand to that mode.Please help me.I am a newbie to android.
Below is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#757575"
        ></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Hotel Name / City /Code"
        android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:background="@color/AddButtonColor"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"></View>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:text="Check In"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#757575"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have fixed View width with `android:layout_width="140dp"` so no matter what is device orientation, its width always be 148dp. If you want to adapt width with orientation then you need to use "match_parent" for `android:layout_width`.

---

Set View width

```
<View
        android:layout_width="140dp"
```

To

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the view a fixed width. That is creating problem. You should use match_parent to width if you want a divider. So, xml of view should be like

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:background="@color/AddButtonColor"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"></View>
```